# How to insert pictures in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, abap

I am looking for a way to insert pictures dynamically in SAP crystal report using ABAP.

What I have done so far is that I know If I want to change the URL of a picture in crystal report I should go to the picture tab of the picture object (OLE object) and then choose Graphic Location. The problem is that it just only works when I am giving it a local path like "C:\..." what would be the equivalent path in SAP.

In SAP, I have stored my pictures in a folder in MIME Repository and give the location of that picture like this 'SAP/PUBLIC/PIC/1.jpg', but this one is also not working. The reason that I was storing them in MIME repository was that I thought since it is giving me a URL, it should also working in crystal report.

Now, my question is that when I am using my crystal report file in SAP what should be the URL of the image to show it in my crystal report?

P.S. I have no limitation in storing images elsewhere.
Thanks